# NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder

Tags: rest, client, javax

I'm trying to creat a very simple Rest Client.
I,m using: 
Netbeans 8
maven project

dependecies:

```html
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-m01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.24.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

and the code:

```
public class Client_con {

public static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:8000/test";
public static final String PATH_NAME = "/h";
public static void main (String [] args){

   Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

    //WS text get
    WebTarget target = client.target(BASE_URI).path(PATH_NAME);
    String res = target.request().get().readEntity(String.class);
    System.out.println(res);
}
}
```

But I always obtain the same error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
   javax/ws/rs/client/ClientBuilder
      at ah.consumer.Client_con.main(Client_con.java:38)
  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder
       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
       ... 1 more
```

I don't know what I can do...

Answer (score 4):

is there a specific reason you have been using
`<version>2.1-m01</version>`
It is usually recommended to use Final Builds which are stable. Try using this version.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you want to use the `-m01` Version, You can `Maven clean` and `Maven install`. This error can also come up, if the respective jar file is not downloaded properly.

also make sure you are importing the right Class.
 
`import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;`

Hope this helps!

Comment: is that the full stack trace of the Exception??
 did u try Maven clean and Maven install after changing the version

Comment: you can manually check if the jar file is available in the Maven local repository. To check that, go to C:\Users\<Username>\.m2\repository\... check if the jar file is available in the Respective folder.

Comment: also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20763493/clientbuilder-class-not-found) should provide some help to you?